# numpy.array() not converting 3D list into 3D ndarray

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, numpy-ndarray

I am writing a program in which I am attempting to convert a 3D python list into a 3D numpy array.

```py
data = [i for i in pickle.load(open("resources/pickle/infyDataset.pickle", "rb"))]
print(data) # First time

data = np.array(data, dtype=(np.ndarray))
print(data) # Second time

nsamples, nx, ny = data.shape
data = data.reshape((nsamples,nx*ny))
```

The first time, the program outputs:
`>>> [[[0, 616.95], [1, 617.95] ... [373, 609.95], [374, 611.1]]]`

An the second time, it outputs:
`>>> [list([[0, 742.8], [1, 742.05] ... [373, 745.35], [374, 745.3]])]`

It should be a numpy array with shape `(261, 375, 2)`, but it returns an array with shape `(261,)` instead. I believe the problem is due to the fact that is interpreting the data as an array of elements which are `<class 'list'>`, instead of `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>`.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: `np.asarray` should do, but also `np.array` without the dtype field should be enough, not sure as I cannot reproduce your issue, I get an array of objects by forcing dtype, by they still have the correct shape

Comment: I've tried `np.asarray` and `np.array`, but none of these convert the array into the shape they should be in.

Comment: What's the `dtype`?  I think it's an object dtype array containing 261 lists - lists that vary in length.  If they differ in length, `np.array` can't make a 3d regular array, so it falls back on making an object array - which is similar to a list.

Comment: Thank you, I just realised that one of the lists is 374 items long, instead of 375. This must be the problem.